# WinSCP and PuTTY integration not working

Tags: putty, winscp

I ssh to EC2 all the time, using both PuTTY and WinSCP. I recently discovered the `Commands > Open in PuTTY` function in WinSCP, however it does not seem to work. When connecting I get this error (PuTTY):

> Network error: Connection refused

And this is the error in PuTTY's event log:

```
2018-05-23 22:40:11 Connecting to ::1 port 22
2018-05-23 22:40:11 We claim version: SSH-2.0-PuTTY_Release_0.70
2018-05-23 22:40:12 Failed to connect to ::1: Network error: Connection refused
2018-05-23 22:40:12 Connecting to 10.8.x.x port 22
2018-05-23 22:40:13 Failed to connect to 10.8.x.x: Network error: Connection refused
2018-05-23 22:40:13 Connecting to 192.168.x.x port 22
2018-05-23 22:40:14 Failed to connect to 192.168.56.1: Network error: Connection refused
2018-05-23 22:40:14 Connecting to 192.168.x.x port 22
2018-05-23 22:40:15 Failed to connect to 192.168.x.x: Network error: Connection refused
2018-05-23 22:40:15 Network error: Connection refused
```

(IP addresses partially redacted with x.x)

Clearly the issue is with the IP it is connecting to (first line)

```
2018-05-23 22:40:11 Connecting to ::1 port 22
```

This is how a working event log looks like:

```
2018-05-23 22:44:01 Connecting to o.o.o.o port 22
2018-05-23 22:44:01 We claim version: SSH-2.0-PuTTY_Release_0.70
2018-05-23 22:44:01 Server version: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4
2018-05-23 22:44:01 Using SSH protocol version 2
2018-05-23 22:44:01 Doing ECDH key exchange with curve Curve25519 and hash SHA-256
2018-05-23 22:44:02 Server also has ecdsa-sha2-nistp256/ssh-rsa host keys, but we don't know any of them
2018-05-23 22:44:02 Host key fingerprint is:
2018-05-23 22:44:02 ssh-ed25519 256 <removed>
2018-05-23 22:44:02 Initialised AES-256 SDCTR client->server encryption
2018-05-23 22:44:02 Initialised HMAC-SHA-256 client->server MAC algorithm
2018-05-23 22:44:02 Initialised AES-256 SDCTR server->client encryption
2018-05-23 22:44:02 Initialised HMAC-SHA-256 server->client MAC algorithm
2018-05-23 22:44:02 Reading key file "<removed>"
2018-05-23 22:44:02 Pageant is running. Requesting keys.
2018-05-23 22:44:02 Pageant has 1 SSH-2 keys
2018-05-23 22:44:02 Configured key file not in Pageant
2018-05-23 22:44:02 Offered public key
2018-05-23 22:44:02 Offer of public key accepted
2018-05-23 22:44:02 Sent public key signature
2018-05-23 22:44:02 Access granted
2018-05-23 22:44:02 Opening session as main channel
2018-05-23 22:44:03 Opened main channel
2018-05-23 22:44:03 Allocated pty (ospeed 38400bps, ispeed 38400bps)
2018-05-23 22:44:03 Started a shell/command
```

Where `o.o.o.o` in line 1 represents the public IP of the EC2 instance.

Any idea why the connection is `::1` from WinSCP and not the proper IP address?

When I hold down <kbd>Ctrl+Shift</kbd> while clicking on `Open in PuTTY` this is the content of the clipboard:

```
"C:\Program Files\PuTTY\putty.exe" -load aws-ubuntu
```

`aws-ubuntu` being the name of a configuration/site in WinSCP.

Answer (score 1):

When you have a stored session in PuTTY that matches a name of the current site in WinSCP, WinSCP will instruct PuTTY to use that session, instead of passing WinSCP settings to PuTTY.

See https://winscp.net/eng/docs/integration_putty#session_configuration

That's your case (`-load aws-ubuntu`).

It seems that your `aws-ubuntu` session in PuTTY is not configured the same as WinSCP `aws-ubuntu` site.

Remove or fix the `aws-ubuntu` session in PuTTY.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT I do not see how this relates to this question. If you have a problem, post a new question.